# How do i find a path through a boolean array?

Tags: algorithm

Here's a question I came across on an interview forum:

> You have an array filled with 0s and 1s. A 0 represents burning lava,
>   and a 1 represents a stepping stone. You start at the beginning of the
>   array, and you want to find the fastest way to reach the end. At each
>   time step, you can either increase or decrease your velocity V by 1,
>   or you can jump to a stepping stone V steps away. You want to reach
>   the end of the array without overshooting.

What is a good algorithm to solve this?

I tried a few things (mostly using dynamic programming and recursion), but I couldn't figure out an optimal substructure that would lead to a non exponential algorithm. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

At each step you have two choices: increasing velocity, or not increasing the velocity. Then, for each of these options, you end up at a different step and the choice repeats. Maybe you can see the tree pattern emerging here. Each node in the tree is a step and each edge is a choice. Each node (step) has two edges (choices), so it is a binary tree.

Also note that if you are at a step *x* with a velocity *V*, then it doesn't matter how you got there, the result of what follows will be the same. So here you can optimize a bit. (For example, using dynamic programming.)

The brute-force approach would be to just imagine this tree and do a depth-first search until you reach the end step exactly. There may be multiple solutions, and the fastest one is *the* solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Programming is the right approach here.

Your search space is two-dimensional: the current position is your first dimension, and the current velocity is the second dimension. This means that you need a 2D array `best[N][N]`, where `N` is the number of items in the boolean array. The value at `best[s,v]` represents the smallest number of steps required to reach position of `s` with the velocity of `v`. Examine each point of the search space to check if a stepping stone can be reached with the current velocity. If the answer is "yes", set the corresponding spot in the search space. Also set the points for adjacent speeds. The answer would be at the position `best[N-1][0]`.